# CTE is very slow after migration

Tags: sql-server

Is there any specific settings that tell the SQL server to make the CTE fast?

We faced a problem when we moved our database from SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2014.

- A query was taking 0 seconds to execute on the old server,now  it takes now 7 seconds on the new server
- A function was taking 4 minutes and 27 seconds +/- 3 seconds to execute, now it takes infinity.

Moreover, the disks on the new server are SSD while on the old are HDD, the new server rams are 32GB while the old was 12GB.

anyone knows if there is any special configuration that we should apply on the new server?

these the sqlplan files

- [New Server](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ifdxhcecx3c797x/2.sqlplan?dl=0) : It takes 7 seconds to execute
- [Old Server](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjw8lqphrfs4l7v/1.sqlplan?dl=0) : It takes 0 seconds to execute

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1936/sql-server-database-migration-checklist/

Comment: Please add corresponding execution plans from old and new servers.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no magic "make my queries fast" switch. You'll have to do it the hard way: Check for missing indices and/or outdated statistics and, if that doesn't help, compare the execution plans on the old and the new server. The good folks on http://dba.stackexchange.com can help you with the latter part.

Comment: I ran sp_updatestats, My Boss was trying to help me, he played in the server settings, It worked for almost 10 minutes then it came back slow, I asked him what he did, He forgot, but the thing that I figured after he played in the server settings, SQL server was occupying 2GB out of 32GB, now its occupying 28GB and only my database is on this server

Comment: @Lijo as image or as XML ? its very long

Comment: Is there any spill over to tempdb? If you post the execution plan we can check more on this. Huge change happened between 2005 and 2014 SQL Server in terms of Cardinality Estimation, which might change the performance, In manier cases it might improve and in some cases it might degrade, For degrading scenarios we need to case by case analysis on the execution plan and provide solution accordingly

Comment: @Ligo i edited my question and I added the sqlplan from both servers

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I added them

Comment: Did you change the compatibility level for the database after upgrade? Look like you could've been bitten by new cardinality estimator.

Comment: @dean yes I changed it to sql 2014

Comment: @dean, the database was with compatibility SQL 2008 , then I changed it manually to SQL 2014, I don't have any knowledge about cardinality estimator, any further help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Here's more info and some advice as well: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/04/01/sql-server-2014s-new-cardinality-estimator-part-1/

Comment: @dean can you write your advice in an answer to accept it? and if you can  tell how to force SQL server to correct the cardinality estimator issue?

Comment: any help will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a significant change in cardinality estimator part of optimizer in SQL Server 2014 in comparison to earlier versions. Given thet cardinality estimates are one of most important factors in shaping an execution plan, this in effect changes the way the queries are executed internally. This change in general almost always work in your favor, producing better and more efficient execution plans, but sometimes it can go the other way around and negatively affect the performance.

There are several things you can do, in order from "easy" to "hard":

- switch back the compatibility level of the database to pre-2014
- enable trace flag 9481 on either server, session or query level (but 
  pls note that querytraceon hint reqires sysadmin privileges)
- freeze the "good" plan with plan guide
- rewrite the affected query to take advantage of the new QE.

Please note that the last and the hardest solution is the best one at the same time, and the easiest is probably the worst.

Here's more info about the change in QE and it's possible effects:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/04/01/sql-server-2014s-new-cardinality-estimator-part-1/

Also about the setting the mentioned trace flag:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2801413